# Django: Generating a queryset from a GET request

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I have a Django form setup using GET method. Each value corresponds to attributes of a Django model. What would be the most elegant way to generate the query? Currently this is what I do in the view:

```
def search_items(request):
    if 'search_name' in request.GET:
        query_attributes = {}

        query_attributes['color'] = request.GET.get('color', '')
        if not query_attributes['color']: del query_attributes['color']

        query_attributes['shape'] = request.GET.get('shape', '')
        if not query_attributes['shape']: del query_attributes['shape']

        items = Items.objects.filter(**query_attributes)
```

But I'm pretty sure there's a better way to go about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it with a list comp and and "interested params" set:

```
def search_items(request):
    if 'search_name' in request.GET:
        interested_params = ('color', 'shape')
        query_attrs = dict([(param, val) for param, val in request.GET.iteritems() 
                            if param in interested_params and val])

        items = Items.objects.filter(**query_attrs)
```

Just for fun (aka don't actually do this) you could do it in one line:

```
def search_items(request):
    items = Items.objects.filter(
        **dict([(param, val) for param, val in request.GET.iteritems() 
                if param in ('color', 'shape') and val])
    ) if 'search_name' in request.GET else None
```

Comment: Just make sure you clean the input.

Comment: @Andrew Sledge:  What's the attack vector are you suggesting cleaning against?

Comment: Never trust user input.  Django request objects are stored in a dict.  Dicts can hold any type of information.  So if you're expecting certain strings but get other "unhealthy" strings, you need to clean them up or dispose of them.

Answer (score 1):

well, the basic way you are approaching the problem seems sound, but the way you wrote it out looks a little funny.  I'd probably do it this way:

```
def search_items(request):
    if 'search_name' in request.GET:
        query_attributes = {}

        color = request.GET.get('color', '')
        if color:
            query_attributes['color'] = color

        shape = request.GET.get('shape', '')
        if shape:
            query_attributes['shape'] = shape

        items = Items.objects.filter(**query_attributes)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be fully dynamic, you can use a little bit of model introspection to find out what fields you can actually query, and filter only using those.

Though, this solution won't allow you to use __lookups in GET parameters, don't know if you need it.

```
def search_items(request):
    if 'search_name' in request.GET:
        all_fields = Items._meta.get_all_field_names()
        filters = [(k, v) for k, v in request.GET.items() if k in all_fields]

        items = Items.objects.filter(*filters)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def search_items(request):
    try:
        items = Items.objects.filter(**dict([
            (F, request.GET[F]) for F in ('color', 'shape')
        ]))

    except KeyError:
        raise Http404
```

Suppose 'color' and 'shape' are required GET params. Predefined tuple of filtering params is prefered because of security reasons.