# How to access the filtered queryset in django admin.SimpleListFilter

Tags: django, django-admin

Say we have two objects:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(length=50)

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    is_bestseller = models.BooleanField()
```

In BookAdmin, if we specify

```
list_filter = ('author', 'is_bestseller')
```

the choices given to you for 'author' will always be all the authors in the database, no matter whether they've written a bestseller or not.

I'd like choices of my filters to be limited by the current selection. I attempted to do this in a general manner, using admin.SimpleListFilter,
however, I'm stuck, since:

```
model_admin.get_queryset()
```

returns unfiltered queryset (i.e all objects, not just those currently filtered out by the user).

How do I get the *filtered* queryset of the BookAdmin?

EDIT: To illustrate the problem better, here is my code:

```
class ForeignFieldFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    field = None

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        queryset = model_admin.get_queryset(request).select_related(self.field)
        # ^^^ !!! Returns UNFILTERED queryset - it's not affected by other filters

        field_ids = queryset.values_list(self.field, flat=True)

        for field_value in self.model..objects.filter(id__in=field_ids):
            yield (field_value.pk, str(field_value))

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        value = self.value()

        # Check that any value was passed, if not, return unmodified queryset
        if not value:
            return queryset

        return queryset.filter({'{0}__pk'.format(self.field): value})


def foreign_field_filter_factory(field, model, title=None):
    title = title or (field[:1].upper() + field[1:])
    return type(
        "ForeignFieldFilter_{0}".format(field),
        (ForeignFieldFilter,),
        {
            'field': field,
            'title': title,
            'parameter_name': field,
            'model': model
        })
```

Comment: perhaps there is a bug in `model_admin.get_queryset(request)` as why does it need the request object if not to use the filters found in the query string? ... i'm trying to find the code in django codebase for this call to see what its doing with the request object.  otherwise you could rebuild the filters from the request queryset here yourself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011028/django-generating-a-queryset-from-a-get-request

Comment: That would work, but only if you don't use any custom filters. I do. Also, that would duplicate the work that the ChangeView has to do anyways, thus leading to a slower performance.

Comment: you will never notice any performance difference! only computers could measure the difference.

Comment: A better answer for more recent versions of django is provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36474515/how-to-get-filtered-queryset-in-django-admin/36476084

Answer (score 3):

For BookAdmin

```
class AuthorBestSeller(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'Best selling authors'
    parameter_name = 'bestseller'

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():
            return queryset.filter(author_id=self.value())
        else:
            return queryset

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        qs = model_admin.get_queryset(request)
        query_attrs = dict([(param, val) for param, val in request.GET.items()])
        qs = qs.filter(**query_attrs)
        for book in qs.filter(is_bestseller=1):  # or might be able to use yeild here
            ret.append((book.author_id, book.author))
        return ret
```

edit: humm... this won't quite work either. it will just give you a list of authors with best sellers.

then add to BookAdmin

```
list_filter = (AuthorBestSeller, )
```

Comment: You got it the other way around - I want to have a filter for the Book class, which respects currently filtered queryset.

Comment: If I select is_bestseller to true, I am still offered all authors. Even if they do not match the search (there is no book they wrote which is bestseller).

Comment: I can override ```choices```, but that will not help me. I need to access the **filtered queryset** to perform the logic. Calling get_queryset() on ```ModelAdmin``` instance will only give me unfiltered queryset.

Comment: That's not right. I can override lookups, I did, but I can only access the unfiltered queryset via model_admin.get_queryset(). I pasted my code in the question, please, read the post carefully again. It's not the simple problem, and yes, I have read the documentation multiple times.

Comment: Also, I believe your example does not work. You're returning list of ```(book.author_id, book.author)``` values in the ```lookups()```, however, in ```queryset()``` you're expecting '1' or '0' as a ```self.value()```. It does not work that way, self.value() will return the selected ```book.author_id```.

Comment: updated and fixed; should work now (or need a little tweaking as of course i can't test on your model :) ) @Enuy

Comment: This will work with simple attribute filters, but will not work with custom admin.SimpleListFilter filters, which can have arbitrary logic in their queryset() filtering.

Comment: so then you have to capture that and repeat it.. yes not DRY or desired; but currently django doesn't support it any other way.  Other option is to try and override the template and rendering processes as well.

Comment: hi warath-coder, i had been running out of same issue. when i used your suggested answer queryset has been called twice. Please explain

Comment: `qs = model_admin.get_changelist_instance(request).get_queryset(request)` also doesnt work because recalculating the queryset invokes the custom filter code, causing an infinite loop.